# \RedeclareSectionCommand introduces paragraph indentation

Tags: koma-script, indentation

When using `\RedeclareSectionCommand` a paragraph indentation is introduced:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}% introduces a paragraph indentation
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter heading}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

How can this be avoided (of course, one could manually work with `\noindent`), but I am wondering whether there is a modification of `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to achieve the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the next KOMA-Script Version (3.26, current is 3.25) there will be an option `afterindent`. Then you can use:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2018/10/23]% needs at least pre-release of version 3.26
\usepackage{blindtext}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterindent=false]{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter heading}
\blindtext[2]

\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

The code can be tested using the [pre-release from the KOMA-Script website](https://komascript.de/node/1801). Default setting is `afterindent=bysign`, so [the answer by @David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458551/43317) will work with version 3.26, too.

Result:

[image]

Comment: :-) I thought there might be a such an option and even checked the manual before posting the classic -ve length version, an option to control this  seems a good idea. The OP should switch the tick over to this answer as it is (or will be) a better answer...

Answer (score 5):

Use a negative but invisible length

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp]{chapter}% 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter heading}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: ... that is brilliant... thanks a lot David!